# Jenkins jdk manager missing

Tags: java, jenkins

I have Jenkins server running the most recent version 2.34.

I want to setup multiple JDK installations, however the JDK tab under `Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System"` is missing.

**Is that a bug or was it actually removed?**

**If so - what is the alternative?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Jenkins 2.34 this is now under the 'Global Tool Configuration'.